# Checkbox within a datagrid, findcontrol issue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid

Keep in mind that for this I am limited to using ASP .NET 1.1, as for this environment I cannot upgrade to 2.0 or beyond

Essentially, I have a very simple datagrid that has a checkbox in one of the columns, which is a template column...the code for the datagrid is this:

```
   <asp:datagrid id="dgDates" OnItemCommand="gridEventHandler" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px"
    CellPadding="3" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlign="Left" AllowSorting="True"
    OnSortCommand="SortData" OnItemDataBound="gridItemDataBound">
    <HeaderStyle Font-Underline="True" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="Black"
     BackColor="#D4D0C8"></HeaderStyle>
    <Columns>
     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="strParameterName" SortExpression="strParameterName" HeaderText="Parameter Name"></asp:BoundColumn>
     <asp:BoundColumn DataField="dtParameterValue" SortExpression="dtParameterValue" HeaderText="Parameter Value"></asp:BoundColumn>
     <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="blnStatic">
      <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBox ID="cbStaticRolling" OnCheckedChanged="staticRolling_CheckedChanged" Runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:CheckBox>           

      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
   </asp:datagrid>
```

Now, I want to evaluate a stored proc based on whether a checkbox for a particular row is set to true or not, so I have this as an eventhandler for the datagrid:

```
    Protected Sub gridItemDataBound(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridItemEventArgs)
        If IsPostBack Then
            Dim intRptSchedulingDatesID As Integer

            If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then
                cbStaticRolling = CType(e.Item.FindControl("cbStaticRolling"), CheckBox)

                intRptSchedulingDatesID = CType(e.Item.DataItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Item("intRptSchedulingDatesID")
                If cbStaticRolling.Checked Then
                    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings(Web.Global.CfgKeyConnStringADMIN), "dbo.spRptSchedulingDate_update", intRptSchedulingDatesID, True)
                ElseIf Not cbStaticRolling.Checked Then
                    SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings(Web.Global.CfgKeyConnStringADMIN), "dbo.spRptSchedulingDate_update", intRptSchedulingDatesID, False)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Now, my issue is that when I set cbStaticRolling to the CheckBox control through FindControl on the e argument, it seems to set the variable okay, but doesn't seem to be setting the right one, or setting it properly, because "Checked" property is false regardless of whether I check the box or not

Comment: when do you databind this grid? OnInit or OnLoad?

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting the value for the checkbox for when it is bound to the result set, in your template column you need something like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label id="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FirstName") %>' >
   </asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Since you are setting a checkbox, you might have to use the value tag instead of the text, and  return true or false from the stored proc.